Need form code with better alignment, uniform field sizes, and simplified styling for a cleaner look
This form is designed to handle different message type.
My problem is lookup select component that fetches and displays the counterparty information based on a query condition for ex cpty_id and tp_platform these fields are causing issues.
I need to make changes in the form code to make sure that every input field within the same row has the same size but I am so unable to do so, Can someone help me in this regard ?
Please find the attached picture for more details.
<portal-form class="q-gutter-md" style="max-width: 1000px; border-radius: 10px; box-shadow: 1 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); background-color: white; padding: 1px;">

  <!-- Radio Select for Different Recall Message Types-->
   <div style="font-weight: bold;">
    <radio-select
      field="recallType"
      label="Message Type:"
      :options="recallTypeOptions"
      required
      @update:value="updateStatus"
      style="margin-bottom: 20px; font-size: 18px; color: #333;"
    />
  </div>

  <!-- Conditional rendering based on selected recall type -->
  <template v-if="formData.recallType">
  
    <!-- Mandatory Fields -->
    <div style="margin-bottom: 20px; font-size: 18px; font-weight:bold; color: #333;">{{ i18n.translate('mandatoryFields') }}</div>
    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
      <text-input field="trade_ref_no" required :max-length="16" class="col-6" style="border-radius: 5px; padding: 23px; border: 1px solid #ccc; box-sizing: border-box;"/>
      <lookup-select field="cpty_id" result-field="userIdentifierOrganisationAddress" :query-condition="counterpartyQueryCondition" required class="col-6" style="border-radius: 5px; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; box-sizing: border-box;"/>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
      <text-input field="cusip_isin" required class="col-6" :max-length="12" style="border-radius: 5px; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; box-sizing: border-box;"/>
      <number-input field="qty" required min="0.000001" max="999999999.999999" fixed-fraction-digits="6" class="col-6" style="border-radius: 5px; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; box-sizing: border-box;"/>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
      <text-input v-if="showRejectionField" field="rejection_reason" exists :max-length="40" class="col-12" style="border-radius: 5px; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; box-sizing: border-box;"/>
    </div>

    <!-- Added space -->
    <div style="margin-bottom: 40px;"></div>
    
    <!-- Nested Sections if all mandatory fields are filled -->
    <template v-if="formData.trade_ref_no && formData.cpty_id && formData.cusip_isin && formData.qty">
      
      <!-- Recall Party Details -->
      <div style="margin-top: 30px; font-size: 18px; font-weight:bold; color: #333;">{{ i18n.translate('partyDetails') }}</div>
      <div class="q-pl-md">
        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
          <text-input field="cuid" upper-case :max-length="4" class="col-4" style="border-radius: 5px; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; box-sizing: border-box;"/>
          <text-input field="borrower_type" :max-length="20" class="col-4" style="border-radius: 5px; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; box-sizing: border-box;"/>
        <!-- New Reference Data Setup for TP Platform -->
        <lookup-select field="tp_platform" result-field="tp_platform" :query-condition="tpPlatformQueryCondition"  class="col-6" style="border-radius: 5px; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; box-sizing: border-box;"/>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
          <text-input field="client_lei" :max-length="20" class="col-6" style="border-radius: 5px; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; box-sizing: border-box;"/>
          <text-input field="cpty_lei" :max-length="20" class="col-6" style="border-radius: 5px; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; box-sizing: border-box;"/>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Add space -->
      <div style="margin-bottom: 40px;"></div>

      <!-- Recall Trade Details -->
      <div style="margin-top: 30px; font-size: 18px; font-weight:bold; color: #333;">{{ i18n.translate('tradeDetails') }}</div>
      <div class="q-pl-md">
        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
          <text-input field="ticker" :max-length="4" class="col-4" style="border-radius: 5px; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; box-sizing: border-box;"/>
          <number-input field="rate" min="0.000001" max="999.999999" fixed-fraction-digits="6" class="col-4" style="border-radius: 5px; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; box-sizing: border-box;"/>
          <number-input field="lot" min="0.000001" max="999999999.999999" fixed-fraction-digits="6" class="col-4" style="border-radius: 5px; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; box-sizing: border-box;"/>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
          <single-select field="dividend_rate" :options="dividend_rateOptions" class="col-4" style="border-radius: 5px; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; box-sizing: border-box;"/>
          <single-select field="collateral_type" :options="collateral_typeOptions" class="col-4" style="border-radius: 5px; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; box-sizing: border-box;"/>
          <single-select field="trade_pledge" :options="trade_or_pledgeOptions" class="col-4" style="border-radius: 5px; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; box-sizing: border-box;"/>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
          <text-input field="internal_trade_id" :max-length="16" class="col-6" style="border-radius: 5px; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; box-sizing: border-box;"/>
          <text-input field="trade_description" :max-length="40" class="col-6" style="border-radius: 5px; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; box-sizing: border-box;"/>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Add space -->
      <div style="margin-bottom: 40px;"></div>

      <!-- Recall Dates Details -->
      <div style="margin-top: 30px; font-size: 18px; font-weight:bold; color: #333;">{{ i18n.translate('datesDetails') }}</div>
      <div class="q-pl-md">
        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
          <date-input field="trade_date" class="col-4" style="border-radius: 5px; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; box-sizing: border-box;"/>
          <date-input field="recall_date" class="col-4" style="border-radius: 5px; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; box-sizing: border-box;"/>
          <date-input field="settlement_date" class="col-4" style="border-radius: 5px; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; box-sizing: border-box;"/>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Add space -->
      <div style="margin-bottom: 40px;"></div>[![enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/AJ6XOmd8.png)](https://i.sstatic.net/AJ6XOmd8.png)

      <!-- Recall Additional Details -->
      <div style="margin-top: 30px; font-size: 18px; font-weight:bold; color: #333;">{{ i18n.translate('additionalDetails') }}</div>
      <div class="q-pl-md">
        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
          <text-input field="open_text_field" :max-length="40" class="col-12" style="border-radius: 5px; padding: 8px; border: 2px solid #ccc; box-sizing: border-box;"/>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
          <text-input v-if="showStatusField" field="status" readonly exists class="col-12" style="border-radius: 5px; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; box-sizing: border-box;"/>
        </div>
      </div>

    </template>
  </template>
</portal-form>


script
export const config: FormV2 = {
  onLoad(setup) {
    setup.initMessageForm();
    if (this.message?.formDataFieldData) {
      setup.setInitialData(this.message.formDataFieldData);
    }
    this.filterCounterpartyOptions();
  },
  beforeSend(action) {
    action.setParameter('payload', JSON.stringify(this.formData));
    action.setParameter('recallKind', this.formData.recallKind);
    action.setFieldUpdate(this.changes());
  },
  translations() {
    return {
      'mandatoryFields': { en: 'Mandatory Fields', de: 'Zahlungsdetails' },
      'tradeDetails': { en: 'Trade Details', de: 'Zahlungsdetails' },
      'finalDetails': { en: 'Final Details', de: 'Zahlungsdetails' },
      'additionalDetails': { en: 'Additional Details', de: 'Zahlungsdetails' },
      'datesDetails': { en: 'Dates', de: 'Zahlungsdetails' },
      'partyDetails': { en: 'Parties', de: 'Zahlungsempfänger' }
    };
  },
  computed: {
    dividend_rateOptions() {
      return ['C', 'NC', 'OT'];
    },
    collateral_typeOptions() {
      return ['C', 'NC', 'OT'];
    },
    trade_or_pledgeOptions() {
      return ['T', 'P'];
    },
    recallTypeOptions() {
      return [
        { value: 'recall_initiate', label: 'Initiate' },
        { value: 'recall_accept', label: 'Accept' },
        { value: 'recall_reject', label: 'Reject' },
        { value: 'recall_cancel', label: 'Cancel' },
        { value: 'recall_close', label: 'Close' }
      ];
    },
    showStatusField() {
      return this.formData.recallType !== 'recall_initiate';
    },
    showRejectionField() {
      return this.formData.recallType === 'recall_reject';
    },
    counterpartyQueryCondition() {
      const currentOrgKey = this.context.userOrganisation.key; // Replace with actual context key

      return {
        and: [
          { fieldKey: '$currentStep', terms: ['ACTIVE'] },
          { fieldKey: '$recordType', terms: ['recall_user_identifier'] }
        ]
      };
    },
    tpPlatformQueryCondition() {
      return {
        and: [
          { fieldKey: '$currentStep', terms: ['ACTIVE'] },
          { fieldKey: '$recordType', terms: ['recall_tp'] }
        ]
      };
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateStatus(value) {
      if (value === 'recall_initiate') {
        this.formData.status = '';
        this.formData.recallKind = 'Initiate';
      } else if (value === 'recall_accept') {
        this.formData.status = 'Accepted';
        this.formData.recallKind = 'Accept';
      } else if (value === 'recall_reject') {
        this.formData.status = 'Rejected';
        this.formData.recallKind = 'Reject';
      } else if (value === 'recall_cancel') {
        this.formData.status = 'Cancelled';
        this.formData.recallKind = 'Cancel';
      } else if (value === 'recall_close') {
        this.formData.status = 'Closed';
        this.formData.recallKind = 'Close';
      }
    },
    filterCounterpartyOptions() {
      const currentOrgKey = this.context.userOrganisation.key; // to be removed

      //  userIdentifierOrganisationAddress check 
      this.userIdentifierOrganisationAddress = this.userIdentifierOrganisationAddress.filter(
        option => option.key !== currentOrgKey
      );
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      userIdentifierOrganisationAddress: [] // to be removed 
  }
};

I adjusted the class and style attributes to ensure that these fields are aligned correctly. but no luck
